# OpenSSL Encryption "zero length password" Error

Tags: php, openssl

This is what I have:

```
$password = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(245);
$passwdtemp = tempnam('/tmp', mt_rand());
file_put_contents($passwdtemp, $password);
passthru('openssl aes-256-cbc -salt -in infile.png -out outfile.png -kfile ' . $passwdtemp;
```

Once every hundred times or so, passthru would give me error "zero length password", passed from OpenSSL. This is different from the error 'unable to read key from /private/tmp/7503675258rhTiX', which occurs when the file doesn't exist.

I'm feeling it has something to do with the password generated by openssl_random_pseudo_bytes. Any way to get this to work properly?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens to the `$password` after it's generated?

Comment: @AdamLiss Oops. I accidentally a line along with many debugging lines. It's saved using file_put_contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [OpenSSL docs](http://openssl.org/docs/apps/enc.html#), the `-kfile` option reads the password from the first line in a file.  That implies the password contains text, not binary data.

If your random data happens to start with a newline character, then the first "line" in the file is empty.  So I'll guess that the problem occurs once every two hundred fifty-six times or so.  :-)

Try converting `$password` from binary to printable hex characters before you store it in the file, or (if you want a larger key space) throw away unprintable bytes.

You may also want to ensure the file is readable only by you; otherwise the password is available for snooping.

Comment: Thank you. Regenerating the password to remove newline and null seemed to fix this.